# CentOS VM not resolving to correct IP

Tags: domain-name-system

I have configured a primary DNS server in centOS and it seems to be working fine. I then configured a secondary DNS in another CentOS VM, but there is a problem. 
When I try to ping the domain which is `abc.com` it resolves to some different IP and FQDN. This is what I get:

[Ping to domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjsHx.png)

I can ping fine from the primary. Here is my `/etc/resolv.conf` for the secondary DNS server:

```
search abc.com
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.1.2
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Here is the `/etc/hosts` for the secondary DNS server:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM2ev.png)

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. I am confused because pinging `abc.com` from the secondary serer resolves 192.168.1.1 which is correct.
Here is bind configuration for primary DNS server:
[This is /etc/named.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrFKp.png)
[/etc/named.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc9V0.png)
[Forward lookup zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUshZ.png)
[Reverse lookup zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIM2N.png)

[Here is secondary serer /etc/named.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfUzY.png)
[secondary server /etc/named.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C364a.png)

Comment: Why on earth would you put a bunch of config files as screenshots?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots when you should copy and paste instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Please let me know what I am doing wrong. I am confused because pinging abc.com from the secondary serer resolves 192.168.1.1 which is correct.

You **do not own** `abc.com`. The result of `abc.com` resolving to `199.181.132.250` is correct behaviour.

From the sounds of it, you are looking to set up the servers as *resolvers* and *authoritative* name servers. Firstly, I don't know of (any?) name-server software which consults local hosts file or resolv.conf file for received queries.

To achieve what you want to do, you need to firstly set up a recursive resolver and an authoritative server. BIND 9 covers both of these aspects

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-an-authoritative-only-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Adding entries to the /etc/hosts file does not make the server a name-server. Infact these files are only used locally as a first point of resolving before asking the DNS.

Comment: I have configured bind. I am updating the question with Primary DNS server bind configuration.

Comment: The secondary serer is not able to get transfer from the primary DNS server and I am assuming it is because it can't resolve

Comment: Firstly, using `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4` is going to cause problems since these and your nameservers are going to disagree on abc.com. Secondly, is 192.168.1.2 setup as a slave server in BIND? From the secondary server, try `dig axfr @192.168.1.1 abc.com`.

Comment: When I do dig it says it is unreachable. In the config file you can see I have specified 192.168.1.2 to have the files transfered

Comment: Could you pastebin the output of the command? The `allow-transfer` directive on the primary name-server doesn't cause transfers. It's a statement that says "If 192.168.1.2 asks for a zone transfer, I'll allow it and transfer the zone". The secondary name server needs to be configured to be a slave for the two zones, and have 192.168.1.1 be configured as the master.